# How to use PHP variables in schema code?

Tags: javascript, php, schema

I have been making a website with dynamic content and have been trying to implement schema code recently. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
          "itemListElement": [{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@id": "http://panpact.com/",
              "name": "Home"
            }
          },{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
              "@id": "<?php echo 'http://panpact.com/audio/$idArticle/$donetitle16'; ?>",
              "name": "audio"
            }
          },{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 3,
            "item": {
              "@id": "<?php echo 'http://panpact.com/audio/$idArticle/$donetitle16'; ?>",
              "name": "<?php echo $title; ?>"
            }
          }]
        }
      </script>
```

As you can see I am trying to use PHP to echo out the @id and name variable but that dosnt seem to be valid. I checked it using a schema verification tool and it did not detect it. I also tried using javascript variables but that did not work either. How can I use a php value in my schema code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to concatenate the strings and variables using the . (dot) operator.

```
"@id": "<?php echo 'http://panpact.com/audio/' . $idArticle . '/' . $donetitle16; ?>",
```